# How camel-quartz work in a cluster

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, quartz-scheduler

Normally quartz scheduler needed to configure datasource to work in a cluster.
[Configure Clustering with JDBC-JobStore](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering)
Is this same when it comes to camel-quartz as well. Can some one explain how camel-quartz work in a cluster.